# Run-Time Error for TableViewDataSource file is separated

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, datasource, tableview

When I separated a ViewController included in TableView and TableViewDataSource files, 
I got a run-time error :  "..EXC_BAD_ACCESS ..".

There is whole source below.

```
// ViewController file
<ViewController.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@end

<ViewController.m>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    **DS1 *ds = [[DS1 alloc] init];**        
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    **_tableView.dataSource = ds;**
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}



// TableViewDataSource file 

<DS1.h>
@interface DS1 : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataList;
@end


<DS1.m>
#import "DS1.h"

@implementation DS1
@synthesize dataList = _dataList;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];    
    if (self) {        
        _dataList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"banana", @"orange", nil]; 
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [_dataList count];
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

If I change the code of ViewController.m from

```
     _tableView.dataSource = ds;
```

to

```
     _tableView.dataSource = self;
```

, then it's ok. (Of course, after DataSource methods had been appended to ViewController.m)

I cannot find any problems, help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this is ARC you have to create an instance variable or a `@property` for your dataSource.
You allocate your dataSource `ds` as a local variable. But the `dataSource` property of the tableView does not retain `ds`. So at the end of `viewDidLoad` ARC will release `ds` and it gets deallocated.

save ds as a property of your viewController. like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DS1 *dataSource;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  // <-- !!!
    self.dataSource = [[DS1 alloc] init];
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy... Is there a way to debug these crashes?